# Unable to remove Chip from UI

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

### Unable to delete Chips.

Here is the list of Data for Chip in **chipDetails**.

`List<Map> chipDetails= new List<Map>();`

---

Below is the function to create Chips and Its **onDeleted** function.
Data is getting deleted from **chipDetails** List but it's on Reflecting on UI.

```
//For creating the input chip
  Widget selectPlayerAsChip(String playerId,String playerName, String playerImage){

    Map data = {"id":playerId,"name":playerName,"profile_pic":playerImage};
    chipDetails.add(data);

    return Chip(
      avatar: profileIconSelector(playerImage,playerName,10.0),
      label: Text('$playerName'),
      onDeleted: (){
        setState(() {
          chipDetails.removeWhere((Map info) {
            return playerName == info["name"];
          });
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: You need to put "context" for selectPlayerAsChip widget.  there are many way to do that. You can try wrap the selectPlayerAsChip in Builder widget or create a new statefull widget, inside build() return selectPlayerAsChip;

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57715410/how-do-i-remove-a-widget-in-response-to-user-input) might help you, but you need to modify this code a bit

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a wrap to make a list of chips in a stateful dialog.
These YouTube vids helped: https://youtu.be/PxcbT1wGkUo https://youtu.be/FGfhnS6skMQ https://youtu.be/Fd5ZlOxyZJ4

```
Wrap(
  spacing: 6.0,
  runSpacing: 6.0,
  children: List<Widget>.generate(myList.length, (int index) {
    return Chip(
      label: Text(myList[index]),
      onDeleted: () {
        setState(() {
          myList.removeAt(index);
        });
      },
    );
  }),
)
```